# Is it safe to have two different git clients accessing the same local git repo at the same time?

Tags: git, egit

I have a local git repo cloned from bitbucket.com I do a lot of work on it. Since eclipse is my IDE I am using EGit eclipse plugin which works great especially when i am refactoring, I am happy with EGit so far.

Today I notice that Atlassian has a nice free GUI shell called SourceTree http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ and I am wondering if there are any issues if my local git repo is being accessed from both EGit and SourceTree at the same time. For example what happens if I start a commit from Egit and then at the same time start a comit from SourceTree? How does git deal with concurrent access of a local repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bounce back and forth between [Gitbox](http://gitboxapp.com/) and command-line Git on my local repos with no problems. The important thing is that the GUI refreshes often enough that it doesn't get "behind" the actual repo on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be fine as long as you only pull from it. The central repo, if not bare, should pull from the others. You want to avoid pushing anything to a non-bare repo.